# Vue: мутация глобального состояния модуля

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Дорогие товарищи матерые! Вопрос касательно vuex для vue.js; Мой store разбит на модули. Мне нужно менять глобальное состояние модуля используя mutation, а не action. Таким образом я хочу менять глобальное состояние через commit. В оф. документации приведен пример с action, где rootState передается в dispatch, мне нужно делать тоже, но передавать в commit. Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commit('ModuleName/MUTATION_NAME', null, {root: true});`

Comment: this.$store.commit('updateUserData', response.data, {root: true}); - где updateUserData это мутация модуля. Так не работает =)

Comment: @АлександрВеликий так, а откуда вы мутацию вызываете? Если из компонента, то указывается как `this.$store.commit('Module/MUTATION', payload)`, если вы вызываете мутацию из модуля, а эта мутация должна вызывать внутри себя другую мутацию из другого модуля, то тогда это делается так, как я в ответе написал.

Comment: я вызываю мутацию из компонента. Я разобрался, при использовании модуля уровень вложенности изменился, было store.state.user, стало store.state.user.user =)